# Efficient trick for maximal bipartite matching in bigger graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, matching, network-flow

**Problem**: We are given two arrays A & B of integers. Now in each step we are allowed to remove any 2 non co-prime integers each from the two arrays. We have to find the maximal number of pairs that can be removed by these steps.

**Bounds:**
length of A, B <=10<sup>5</sup> 
every integer <=10<sup>9</sup> 
Dinic's algorithm - O(V<sup>2</sup>E) 
Edmonds-karp algorithm - O(VE<sup>2</sup>) 
Hopcroft–Karp algorithm - O(E sqrt(V))

**My approach up till now:** This can be modeled as bipartite matching problem with two sets A and B and edges can be created between every non co-prime pair of integers from the corresponding set.
But the problem is that there can be O(V<sup>2</sup>) edges in the graph and most Bipartite matching and max-flow algorithms will be super slow for such large graphs.

I am looking for some problem specific or mathematical optimization that can solve the problem in reasonable time. To pass the test cases i need at most O(V log V) or O(V sqrt(V)) algorithm.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you get those complexities? Hopcroft-Karp is `O(E sqrt V)`

Comment: sorry , I was thinking about edmonds-karp algorithm.

Comment: It's still wrong. Dinic is `O(V * E^2)` and Hopcroft-Karp is `O(E sqrt V)`.

Comment: sorry , again for Hopcroft–Karp algorithm complexity but i think Dinic's complexity is correct. You are mentioning Edmonds-karp's algorithm's complexity - O(V * E^2). Thank u for correcting again.

Comment: This appears to be derived from an open CodeChef competition problem: http://www.codechef.com/JULY14/problems/GNUM.  Please mention this in your question, so that people can decide whether or not to answer.

Comment: I am sorry my question's similarity . I was searching for a hackerrank's question .

Comment: I have rolled back your edit. You already have answers and even accepted one. Substantial edits at this point don't make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try making a graph with vertices for:

1. A source
2. Every element in A
3. Every prime present in any number in A
4. Every element in B
5. A destination

Add directed edges with capacity 1 from source to elements in A, and from elements in B to destination.

Add directed edges with capacity 1 from each element x in A to every distinct prime in the prime factorisation of x.

Add directed edges with capacity 1 from each prime p to every element x in B where p divides x

Then solve for max flow from source to destination.

The numbers will have a small number of factors (at most 9 because 2.3.5.7.11.13.17.19.23.29 is bigger than 10**9), so you will have at most 1,800,000 edges in the middle.

This is much fewer than the 10,000,000,000 edges you could have had before (e.g. if all 100,000 entries in A and B were all even) so perhaps your max flow algorithm has a chance of meeting the time limit.

Comment: Beautiful, but won't there be at most 2 * 9 * 100,000 = 1.8 million edges, instead of 180,000?  (Not counting the edges from source or to destination.)

Comment: Good point, I've corrected it - it now feels like it may be too slow, oh well back to the drawing board...

Comment: Well, I just wrote a quick Perl script and it turns out there are only 332023 * 2 = 664046 edges if both A and B consist of the last 10^5 numbers in the range.  This is probably not the worst case, but it's also probably not too far off.

Comment: well, this is very good optimization but still dinic's algorithm may be very slow because it is O(V^2E) which is greater than 10^12.